# Better design for blocklists

Tags: database, schema, blocking

I have 10-12 items which i need to maintain a blocklist for on my system. Which design is better? These are sample columns, much more items to block.

**table 1**
b_id
b_email
b_name
b_username
b_pagename
b_word
b_IP
comments

**table 2**
b_id
b_type
text
comments

Basically in table 1, each blocked item is a value in 1 column only, rest are all NULL.
In table 2, each blocked item resides in the only column so there are no NULLs

There are other designs possible too like separate tbl for each item but then there will be lots of tbs just to hold blocklists.

---

EDIT: The use of this data is to block users from performing certain activities. Each blocked item is used in differnt places. Example:

block_IP = list of IP addresses that the website will block based on detected user's IP
block_name = list of restricted first/last names users cannot use to signup with
block_email = list of restricted emails users cannot use to signup with
block_username = list of restricted usernames users cannot use to get a profile name
block_pagenames = list of restricted page names users cannot create
block_word = abusive words which users cannot use within content of comments, blogs, etc.
and the list goes on...

So basically these are all like individual lookup items. In an ideal world we would have separate tables for each item. But I dont like to idea of having 20-30 tables just to hold blocked items values. Should be an easier way to manage all this. Only issue is some items like block_Word can grow to millions of rows as there are a lot of words that can be blocked in many languages.

Comment: Any chance you can provide some sample data to help describe how these tables work? - I'm not sure if I get why table 1 needs more than 2/3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Entity-Attribute-Value approach or use a schemaless NoSQL datastore.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

If you're processing the 'blocking' in the middle tier, you can just dump the lists as serialized objects (e.g. JSON) into the table.

I assume you're trying to do something like access control lists, which depending on your plaform you might be able to find a plugin for.

Comment: I added details up on data usage.

Comment: What kind of framework are you working with, e.g. Rails, Spring, PHP?

Comment: EAV provides a generic solution for this. Your entities would be a unique name for the object it is applied to (e.g. 'User', 'HTTP_ENV_VARS', ..) the attributes are predicates of the entity ('email', 'REMOTE_IP',...) and the values your `blocklist` ('test@test.com', '10.1.1.1'...).